# Is a partially topological group completely regular

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $\mathcal T$ be a topology on $G$ and the function
$$
\begin{align*}
&f:G\times G\to G\\
&f(x,y)=xy^{-1}
\end{align*}
$$
be continuous at $(1,1)$.

Is $(G,\mathcal T)$ completely regular?

Comment: No: Take the trivial topology on G.

Comment: The trivial topology is completely regular. With it the group is a topological group and any topological group is completely regular.

Comment: Completely regular includes Hausdorff.

Comment: I accept wikipedia's definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space. Otherwise I would say Tychonov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $B_n=\{k\in\Bbb Z:|k|\ge n\}$. (Note: $0\in\Bbb N$.) Let $G$ be $\Bbb Z$ under addition, and let $\mathscr{T}=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. The only nbhd of $0$ is $B_0=\Bbb Z$ itself, so $$f:G\times G\to G:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x-y$$ is continuous at $\langle 0,0\rangle$.

$B_1$ is an open nbhd of $1$ whose complement is $\{0\}$; suppose that $\varphi:G\to[0,1]$ is such that $\varphi(1)=0$ and $\varphi(0)=1$. Let $U=(0,1]$, and note that $U$ is an open nbhd of $1$ in $[0,1]$. But $0\in\varphi^{-1}[U]$, and $1\notin\varphi^{-1}[U]$, so $\varphi^{-1}[U]\ne G$ is not a nbhd of $0$, and $\varphi$ is not continuous. Thus, $G$ is not completely regular.

Comment: @user138171: You’re welcome. I haven’t been around since last December, so I’m working my way back through the unanswered general topology questions to see if I can dispose of some of them.